# Filter GridView with TextEditController Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how can filter result of gridview with textediting controller like this code?
**Flutter Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:roboqbo/Model/Ricetta.dart';

import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import '../../Controller/Support.dart';
import '../theme/colors.dart';
import 'dettaglio_ricetta_page.dart';

class RicettaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool loadFavorites;
  RicettaPage(this.loadFavorites);

  @override
  State<RicettaPage> createState() => _RicettaPageState();
}

class _RicettaPageState extends State<RicettaPage> {
  TextEditingController value = TextEditingController();
  var listaOld = [];
  var _ratingController;
  var _rating;

  double _userRating = 3.0;
  int _ratingBarMode = 1;
  double _initialRating = 2.0;
  bool _isRTLMode = false;
  bool _isVertical = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Ricette",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: BackButton(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: primary,
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Ricetta>>(
            future: getList(context),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Ricetta>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                return getBody(snapshot.data, context);
              } else {
                return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [CircularProgressIndicator()])
                    ]);
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<List<Ricetta>> getList(BuildContext context) async {
    listaOld = await Ricetta.getListaCloud();
    if (widget.loadFavorites == true) {
      listaOld = listaOld.where((e) => e.isFavorite == true).toList();
    }
    return listaOld;
  }

  Widget getBody(List<Ricetta> lista, BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: value,
              onChanged: (text) {
                try {
                  var values = listaOld.where((o) => o.name == text).toList();
                  setState(() {
                    listaOld = values;
                  });
                } catch (e) {
                  print("errore: " + e);
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
                    states.contains(MaterialState.focused)
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.red),
                iconColor: Colors.red,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                hintText: "Cerca",
                fillColor: Colors.white70,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "images/filtri.png",
                  width: 165,
                  height: 80,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "images/categorie.png",
                  width: 165,
                  height: 80,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(children: [
            RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                var a = await getList(context);
                setState(() {
                  lista = a;
                });
              },
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: Platform.isAndroid
                      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200
                      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 2,
                  child: Expanded(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                          ),
                          itemCount: lista.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => {
                                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                DettaglioRicettaPage(
                                                    lista[index]),
                                          )),
                                    },
                                child: Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        0.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 200,
                                    color: Colors.white70,
                                    child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                              width:
                                                  isTablet == true ? 400 : 190,
                                              height:
                                                  isTablet == true ? 250 : 130,
                                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                                  child: Image.network(
                                                lista[index].picture,
                                                height: isTablet == true
                                                    ? 250
                                                    : 130,
                                                errorBuilder:
                                                    (BuildContext context,
                                                        Object exception,
                                                        StackTrace stackTrace) {
                                                  return Image.asset(
                                                      'images/trofie.png');
                                                },
                                              ))),
                                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                      10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                lista[index].name,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                                child: Container(
                                              width: 10,
                                              child: RatingBar.builder(
                                                initialRating:
                                                    lista[index].isFavorite ==
                                                            true
                                                        ? 1
                                                        : 0,
                                                minRating: 1,
                                                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                                allowHalfRating: true,
                                                itemCount: 1,
                                                itemPadding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        horizontal: 4.0),
                                                itemBuilder: (context, _) =>
                                                    Icon(
                                                  Icons.star,
                                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                                ),
                                                onRatingUpdate: (rating) async {
                                                  await Ricetta.favouriteRecipe(
                                                      lista[index]);
                                                  if (rating == 1) {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      lista[index].isFavorite =
                                                          false;
                                                    });
                                                  } else {
                                                    lista[index].isFavorite =
                                                        true;
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      lista[index].isFavorite =
                                                          true;
                                                    });
                                                  }
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            )),
                                          ]),
                                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Container(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                        10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  lista[index].tempo +
                                                      " minuti",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                                    fontSize: 13,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Container(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                        20.0, 0, 0, 0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "CUCINA>",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.red,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                    fontSize: 12,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ])
                                        ])));
                          })),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```